# How to access other users Azure monitor data?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want to register an app in Azure that has the ability to access Monitor data of other Azure users.

I know you can register a new app...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

...and in there you can select the APIs you will use. I want to access the Monitor/Application Insights data to check on other user's Functions status.
That API list on the app registration page doesn't seem to contain the Monitor API in the list of API permissions.

So what are the proper steps to be able to use the Monitor/Application Insights API of other Azure users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should connect to other users's Azure account and with Token go to the Application Insights API or use SDK.

Here you can have more information about it:
[Azure Active Directory Access Token][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token]

> POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded grant_type=authorization_code
>   &client_id=2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e
>   &code=AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGBCmLdgfSTLEMPGYuNHSUYBrqqf_ZT_p5uEAEJJ_nZ3UmphWygRNy2C3jJ239gV_DBnZ2syeg95Ki-374WHUP-i3yIhv5i-7KU2CEoPXwURQp6IVYMw-DjAOzn7C3JCu5wpngXmbZKtJdWmiBzHpcO2aICJPu1KvJrDLDP20chJBXzVYJtkfjviLNNW7l7Y3ydcHDsBRKZc3GuMQanmcghXPyoDg41g8XbwPudVh7uCmUponBQpIhbuffFP_tbV8SNzsPoFz9CLpBCZagJVXeqWoYMPe2dSsPiLO9Alf_YIe5zpi-zY4C3aLw5g9at35eZTfNd0gBRpR5ojkMIcZZ6IgAA
>   &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345
>   &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F &client_secret=p@ssw0rd
>
> //NOTE: client_secret only required for web apps

With the token you will be able to perform calls to Azure on behalf of the account you are using at.

Once you have it you can call Application Insight Api and Monitor other users's resources and get the AI keys.
https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference

I recommend you to check the [Application Insight SDK][https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet]

Once you have a user's application insight key you can perform any operation on behalf of it.

using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

```
var tc = new TelemetryClient();
tc.InstrumentationKey = "INSERT YOUR KEY";
```

Comment: So the user that I would be viewing does not need to create a Azure AD service principal? They would just authorize my application to see this data? If so that would make sense since that's how most oauth based services work. It's just not very clear in the azure docs.

Comment: Well I did it with Storage Accounts and worked for me, the only thing is that I had to ask for the tenancy to the user because is required to get the token, but I suppose there is a way to get the tenancies for a user logged in a Microsoft account as  for instance in Azure devops once you write your credentials they propose you the list of tenancies associated with your account.  Going through this command to the API it is calling can lead you to get that information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-list